# ScriptableObject identity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Implemented a simple system based on `ScriptableObject`, in which there is a field of type `ItemBase` (reference to the prefab to be spun). And then the question was how best to identify it. Came up with two options.

1. Use a string ID in each `ScriptableObject`. But the problem is that if you change this ID, you will have to manually change it and in the code, where the system is being requested, to initialize it (the object).
2. To use string ID, but in the code not directly, but with the enum generated with all id. The advantage is that if the ID is changed, the code will clearly contain compilation errors, since the required Enum type does not exist (the ID and enum have changed, respectively).
3. Remove the ID in general and use for each `ScriptableObject` object its own separate `ItemBase` type and already call the spawn prefabs like this:

   ```
   T Init <T> () where T: ItemBase
   ```

In the case of ID:

```
ItemBase Init (ItemIdEnum);
T Init <T> (ItemIdEnum) where T: ItemBase
```

Which of these identification options is more correct or offer your own?

Comment: could you please add some code. We can probably understand by reading your meta explenation but it is easier to help you already starting from an existing code. In general: Each `ScriptableObject` instance already **is unique** and has a unique GUID.

Answer (score 0):

SO = Scriptable Object

Unity SO already have an identity and they can, themselves, be used as itentifiers.

You may see a specific example in [this youtube video - 23:41](https://youtu.be/6vmRwLYWNRo?t=23m41s), where a SO may be used as an identifier to replace an enum to differentiate the damage types of a given weapon.

To have an identifier you can just use this code.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Simple Identifier")]
public class J_Identifier : ScriptableObject {}
```

And you can reference it inside other classes, or even inside itself.

```
public class Something : MonoBehaviour
{
    //the instance of the identifier
    J_Identifier identifier;

    private bool CheckIdentifierWith(J_Identifier otherIdentifier) =>
    identifier == otherIdentifier;
}
```

In this regard an SO identifier may also contain any kind of logic, for example you might use the SO as identifier and also store the weapon damage.

```
[CreateAssetMenu(menuName = "Base Weapon")]
public class Weapon : ScriptableObject
{
    public int damage = 5;
}
```

Consider that you might have 2 SO with the same name (but in different folders). BUT these 2 SO identity will be different, so their names does not matter identification-wise.

If you want to store the identity of the SO for other purposes you might just use [GetInstanceId()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.GetInstanceID.html), but I do not see any useful patterns with this approach.

```
//gets the identifier as string
identifier.GetInstanceId().ToString();
```

Comment: In your explanations you confuse "identifier" with "instance" or at least use the two as if they where exchangeable ;)

Comment: I think we had just one example that could be misunderstood. Just updated the answer. Let me know if you see confusing code somewhere else.